# How can i count results in my sql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Maybe someone could tell what is wrong with my code, i can't count my sql data.

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($conn,"
SELECT *
     , COUNT(*) as number 
  FROM saskaitos 
 WHERE saskaita = 'LT280431080121300679'
"); 
echo $query1;
```

I need a query which could count my databases result where saskaita='X'; Maybe someone could give me solution? Thanks.

Comment: You can select and then count using mysqli_count if you also need to use the results later in your application or just count in the query but you cannot do both select and count in MySQL at the same time

Comment: Already tried that, and its not working. Maybe i'm doing something wrong? Here is my code (i need to echo how many rows have the same value with saskaita):

`$result1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM saskaitos WHERE saskaita='LT280431080121300679'");`
`$result2 = mysqli_count("$result1");`
`echo $result2;`

Comment: Check the syntax for mysqli_count but you are on the right track

Comment: I’ll give you an [hint](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_num_rows.asp)

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select data and use count in the same query, as `SELECT *` returns multiple rows and `COUNT` returns 1 row.

Comment: It's still not working when i trying to get values without `SELECT *`. Here is my full code: 
`$query1 = mysqli_query($conn,"COUNT(*) as number FROM saskaitos WHERE saskaita='LT280431080121300679'");`

Comment: try to do the same query directly in your database (PHPmyAdmin) and see if it returns  any rows, if it does then the problem is in your php code. See if your `$conn` can connect to the database, also make sure you save your mysqli_query results into a variable like `$result =  mysqli_query($conn,"COUNT(*) as number FROM saskaitos WHERE saskaita='LT280431080121300679'");` and `echo $result;`